# Getting ConcurrentModificationExecption error in this activity class

Tags: java, android

**Getting error in obsever and at foreach loop, listView model is the viewmodel class and getMovies() is the moviecollection list**

```
private void ObserveAnyChange() {
    moviesListViewModel.getMovies().observe(this, new Observer<List<MoviesData>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<MoviesData> moviesDatas) {

            if(moviesDatas != null) {



                for (MoviesData movies : moviesDatas) {

                    Log.v("Tag", "onChanged: " + movies.getTitle());

                    movieRecyclerAdapter.setmMovies(moviesDatas);

                }

            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: why call `movieRecyclerAdapter.setmMovies(moviesDatas);` inside your for loop ? why even have a for loop ?

Comment: Okay got your point thanks.